# How to sort an excel column using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to sort an excel spreadsheet by sorting one column be ascending numbers so 1,2,3,4,5...

Does anyone know a quick and dirty way to sort a excel column in powershell?

Comment: Have you started working on a script? If so, please post what you have so far. Are you trying to sort only one column, or sort multiple columns based on the values in one column?

Comment: i just put in what i have so far.  this gives me an error tho saying
Exception calling "Sort" with "1" argument(s): "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized."

Comment: actually this code above works.  my first header column was merged with a couple rows so it was preventing to sorting

Comment: Yeah, it was working for me as well. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: I'll move your code to your answer so that it fits with SE guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
    ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
    [System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
    [System.GC]::Collect() 
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
} 
$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 
$objExcel.Visible = $True 
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\flag for errors\1921BB.xls")
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 

$objRange = $objWorksheet.UsedRange 
$objRange2 = $objworksheet.Range("E1")  
[void] $objRange.Sort($objRange2) 
$objWorkbook.Save()
$a = Release-Ref($objWorksheet) 
$a = Release-Ref($objWorkbook) 
$a = Release-Ref($objExcel)
```

Comment: Please come back after 48 hours and [mark this as the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: This script works but I'm having trouble with the Excel file being fully "released". I.e., when I manually open the Excel file after using the script, I get a notification stating that the file is Read Only because it's still in use. When I open Task Manager, the EXCEL process is still running even though the file is closed.

Comment: Problem was fixed by adding `$objWorkbook.Close()` just after the `$objWorkbook.Save()` statement.